# pulling part of a string from SQL database column

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a column called "Memo".  There is data in all the rows that look kinda like:

```
blah blah 08-22-19 Transfer from blah blah blah
```

I am needing to pull out just the "08-22-19 Transfer from". Ideally I would like to pull the info in a temp table with 2 different columns one named "Date" to enter 08-22-2019 and the other "Note" to enter Transfer from. I am having a hard time figuring how to get this done.

The format of the date is always mm-dd-yy but the date can be different — it could be 08-22-19 or 07-29-19.

Basically if table.memo had a row entry that was

```
The day that I did this 08-05-19 - AUDIT TRANSFERRED FROM 073 TO 057 because I wanted to.
```

I would like to be able to pull and insert into a new table like....

```
newtable.Date = 08/22/2019    
newtable.Note = AUDIT TRANSFERRED FROM 073 TO 057
```

What comes before the info I want to pull is all different and so is the following text. There is no pattern to the data before or after the text that I need to pull.

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING` function to get part of string.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp

Comment: As described, this is not a simple problem: Sounds like you need to recognize multiple date formats ("08/22/2019" and "08-05-19") Do you know if there will always be one and only one date in the text? Do you know if it will always follow American formatting? If you don't know those things, your problem becomes harder.

Comment: i know that the format is always mm-dd-yy but the date is always different. it could be 08-22-19 or 07-29-19. Sorry in my example i used / instead of -

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya — it's unlikely that the date is at the same offset in each row; the `blah blah` part of the data is probably of variable length.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  You probably need to look hard at the 'regular expression' functions it provides, to decide which one(s) will help you.  You're trying to split the string into 4 bits, it appears: 'junk-1', 'date', 'commentary', 'junk-2'.  And you'd like to capture 'date' and 'commentary' to be added to another table. 
Creating structure out of unstructured data is hard work.  How can you tell the boundary between 'commentary' and 'junk-2'?

Comment: Very true Jonathan. As I said to the boss I need to make gold out of horse poop. the data came from an Access Database that I wrote an SSIS package to bring it into Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: @user3818712 there is no boundary between commentary and junk-2? This will be hard. I have provided answer but it will work only for the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how the MEMO is structured. If the length is fixed 08-05-19 and AUDIT TRANSFERRED FROM 073 TO 057, you can try below query:

```
DECLARE @sqlstring as varchar(max) = 'the day that i did this 08-05-19 - AUDIT TRANSFERRED FROM 073 TO 057 because I wanted to.'

select 
    substring(@sqlstring, 
        patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', 
                @sqlstring), 8),

    substring(@sqlstring, 
        (patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', 
                @sqlstring))+11, 34)
```

Comment: that got me closer Jervs. I didn't think going down that road. The issue I just seen is  that now I see some entry's that are like mm-dd-yy blah blah blah mm-dd-yy Audit Transferred from....." so that first date entry is messing it up for me. there are over 500,000 rows in this table.

Comment: let's find a solution to that first date entry! :D my concern is the transferred from..... how would you know the last word you'll get!

Comment: You got me close enough that I got it figured out. patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] - Audit Transferred    fixed it